# Looking to vertically align images in a slider to the middle

Tags: css, wordpress

Link: http://mallorca-attraction-tickets.com/product/test-2/

The site is built on wordpress with elementor and woocommerce and uses the plugin "Twist" to display the woocommerce gallery pictures in a slideshow.

The height of the slides has been reduced to 400px using this css

.twist-pgs {
    height: 400px
}

The images are aligned vertically to the top, due to the short height the bottom has been hidden. I am looking for a way to display the images so they are vertically aligned to the middle so a part of the top and bottom is hidden in the slider.

I can not find any css that can do this. Thank you for any help received with this. The owner of the plug in does not know either.

Comment: use  `.slick-list { transform: translateY(-50%);}`  If you have all the image of the same height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
.woocommerce div.product div.images img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 400px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    box-shadow: none;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

That should solve the problem. Do let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your image is aligned by this javascript:

http://mallorca-attraction-tickets.com/wp-content/plugins/twist/assets/slick.min.js?ver=1.3

It dynamically adds the transform to your source code:

```
<div class="slick-track" style="opacity: 1; width: 7980px; transform: translate3d(-3420px, 0px, 0px);">
```

The 0px, 0px are for top and bottom. You can try to set them to the image width / 2 .

But first make a backup of the javascript file.

And there is an option in the javascript file:

```
vertical: false,
```

Maybe it works if you change this one. It adds the class "slick-vertical".
If this doesn`t work, maybe you find another option.

Regards Tom